# How can I send gpg encrypted mail automatically from the linux command line?

Tags: linux, email, gnupg

How can I send gpg encrypted mail automatically from the linux command line?

I'm a little stumped on this one, I've tried using mutt but it doesn't encrypt mail unless it's used interactively.

Does anyone know if you can use the build in mail command to do this some how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try something like

```
gpg -ea -r "Recipient name" -o - filename | mail -s "Subject line" recipient@example.com
```

to send an ascii-armored, public-key-encrypted copy of the file "filename" to a person named "Recipient name" (who is in your gpg keyring) at email address recipient@example.com with the specified subject line.

or

```
echo "Your secret message" | gpg -ea -r "Recipient name" | mail -s "Subject" recipient@example.com
```

to send text directly rather than from a cleartext file on disk.

Comment: Does that sign the message (with your private key) as well?

Comment: Add "s" to the gpg command for that - e.g., gpg -eas -r "John Smith"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for those using msmtp.

`cat <<EOF | gpg -ea -r "recipient gpg name" | msmtp -a "account default" recipient@mail.com
Subject: Hello Kosmos
Type your message here, yada yada yada.
EOF`

voilà