# How to encrypt the mail in unix?

Tags: unix, encryption, sed, awk, mailx

I want to encrypt the mail as that will be containing the confidential information. There are no attachments. Please help in providing the steps to encrypt the mail. I have got the reference of [How can I send gpg encrypted mail automatically from the linux command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/188493/how-can-i-send-gpg-encrypted-mail-automatically-from-the-linux-command-line) link. But I am not satisfied with the answer.

I have used `echo "Your secret message" | gpg -ea -r abc@gmail.com | mail -s "test mail" abc@gmail.com`

But I am getting below error message: gpg: abc@gmail.com: skipped: public key not found gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: public key not found

Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done and what is the best approach ?

Comment: You need the recipient's public key in your key ring.

Comment: How can I generate that ?

Comment: You can't, obviously. If you're going to encrypt something for a particular person, it has to be decrypted using something only that person knows.

Comment: when we send general email from for example GMAIL, there is one option as encrypt. Is the same kind of any option avaiable to us in unix?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying will work, but you need to add the recipient public key to your keyring. To get the key, have the recipient export the key and send it to you. 
The recipient would have to export it, for example:

```
gpg --export -a "abc@gmail.com" > abcgmail.key
```

When you have the key, import it:

```
gpg --import abcgmail.key
```

Once done, your mail command should work.

Comment: After encrypting the mail , do the user need to decrypt the mail explicitely ?